# Can a CoreData model created programmatically from a DTD-XML file?

Tags: xml, core-data, dtd

I have the following DTD-XML file (from MSAccess), and would to use it to create my CoreData model programmatically.

Each ELEMENT here becomes an entity, with a one-to-one relationship to each ATTLIST attribute therein listed.

Is this even possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT league (date, time, version, season, division+)>

<!ELEMENT date EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST date
    year  CDATA #REQUIRED
    month CDATA #REQUIRED
    date  CDATA #REQUIRED
    day   CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT division (team+)>
<!ATTLIST division
    id    CDATA #REQUIRED
    label CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT season EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST season
    season CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT sports-statistics (league)>

<!ELEMENT team EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST team
    id    CDATA #REQUIRED
    city  CDATA #REQUIRED
    name  CDATA #REQUIRED
    alias CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT time EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST time
hour CDATA #REQUIRED
    minute     CDATA #REQUIRED
    second     CDATA #IMPLIED
    timezone   CDATA #REQUIRED
    utc-hour   CDATA #REQUIRED
    utc-minute CDATA #REQUIRED
>

<!ELEMENT version EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST version
    number CDATA #REQUIRED
>
```

Comment: This is possible but (intentionally) undocumented by Apple and thought apples internal ** *.xcdatamodel** packages contain an XML-encoded file called **contents** which represents everything you can see in the Xcode Model Editor. But this changes with every Xcode version.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.

If you're on iOS, you can use the built-in `NSXMLParser` to load that file and run through its contents. Or add [TouchXML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) if you prefer loading the document and inspecting it instead of getting parser callbacks. [Basically, `NSXMLParser` does SAX-style parsing, `TouchXML` uses DOM-style].

Once you've loaded the XML you can create your model. Every aspect of Core Data model creation is available as Core Data API calls, so you don't need to use the model editor. You'll want to

1. Create an instance of `NSManagedObjectModel`
2. Create a new `NSEntityDescription` for each element. Use `[NSManagedObjectModel setEntities:]` to associate these with the model.
3. Create `NSAttributeDescription`s for each attribute and `NSRelationshipDescription`s for each relationship between entity types. Use `[NSEntityDescription setProperties:]` to associate these with the entity description.
4. (optional) Save the `NSManagedObjectModel` so you don't have to do this every time the app launches. `NSManagedObjectModel` doesn't have any of its own methods to save, but it conforms to `NSCoding`, so use that.

Keep in mind that the model is only mutable until the moment when you add a persistent store file. You can only change it when it's just the model with no data. Once you load the data, you have to treat the model as immutable.